# Skype/MS Team REST API not working

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm creating a bot using REST API. Indeed, I want to send a message from my bot to me as following

I start with 'Authentification'

Request:
`curl -k -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_password}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"`

Response:

`{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 0,
  "access_token": "<access_token>"
}`

Next, I start a new conversation

Request:

`POST https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "bot": {
        "id": "standupalice",
        "name": "Standup Alice"
    },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "<my bot id>",
            "name": "Standup Alice"
        },
       {
            "id": "<my user id>",
            "name": "Bao"
        }
    ],
    "topicName": "News Alert"
}`

NOTE:  and  are obtained from a callback message sent from Skype app to Standup Alice bot.

Response:

`{
  "id": "<conversation id>"
}`

It's weird since the conversation ID is identical to  . Well, now I compose a message to send to me as following
Request:

`POST https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations/<conversation id>/activities
Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "<my bot id>",
        "name": "Standup Alice"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "id": "<conversation id>",
        "name": "News Alert"
   },
   "recipient": {
        "id": "<my user id>",
        "name": "Bao"
    },
  "channelId": "skype",
    "text": "My bot's reply"
}`

Response (http error 400 - bad request):

`{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "The conversationId <conversation id>and bot <my bot id> doesn't match a known conversation"
  }
}`

Do you have an idea what's wrong with my requests and parameters?

Note 1: I tried to fire request to https://**api**.botframework.com/v3/conversations as described in https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/overview/#navtitle, but always receives http error 404 - Resource not found.

Note 2: I just tried the same way for webchat and it works fine, but MS Teams doesn't work (http error 500 - Internal Server Error)

Note 3: my channel settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your second API request (the one starting a conversation) should have returned something looking like this:

```
{
   "activityId": "string",
   "serviceUrl": "string",
   "id": "string"
}
```

The fact that it didn't suggests to me that that's where the problem is (although full disclosure, I wasn't able to re-create it).

Looking at your "members" array, I see you added the bot.  I'm not sure, strictly speaking, that a bot is a member (I think members are human, but I can't find a good definition).  So, my best suggestion would be to remove the bot from the members array in that second API call.

Good luck!